# access call logs through iPhone

Tags: iphone, calllog

Is there any way to access the call logs.
The number from which the call has came and the duration for how long the call lasted?

Also can we record the call in our application if our application is running in the background.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for iOS4, but no for iOS5.

More info here, including sample code
http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

There is at least one application in iTunes (calLog), which seems to have implemented this. Maybe that's why Apple disabled it in iOS5...

Answer (score 1):

No (non of the two), not in official SDK, apple will not allow it as it sees it as a privacy breach.