# How to get the Recents List and Favorites List in iphone

Tags: iphone, contacts, favorites, recent-file-list

I want to get the default iphone Contact Favorites List & Recents List in iOS.Please help me.

Comment: Google it first, StackOverflow it next

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the Favorite list and recent call list using ios sdk.Call logs are inaccessible in iPhone.You can only get the contacts using Address Book.

Check the following links

[iPhone call log / history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history)

[access call logs through iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714071/access-call-logs-through-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Other posters are correct, you cannot access Favorites list. But you can do some smart analysis of the Address Book to find more "important" contacts:

https://medium.com/growth-engineering-notebook/generate-better-referrals-by-analyzing-the-address-book-5d567f9dcf38